# If the JSF Implementation is a server-wide configuration setting in WAS, why is it set at the application level in Admin Console?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere, myfaces

The IBM documentation says, "The JSF implementation is a server-wide configuration setting" (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html) in version 8.0 and later of WebSphere Application Server, but the instructions say to go here:

Applications > Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications > **application_name** > JSP and JSF options

to configure the setting.

On the WAS page itself where you set this parameter, it says:

> **JSF implementation**
>
> On version 8.0 and later nodes, the JSF implementation is a server-wide configuration setting. Thus, if you have multiple applications that require different JSF implementations, you must separate the applications into different application servers or clusters. On version 7.0 nodes, the JSF implementation is an application configuration setting. Read the topic in the information center about configuring JavaServer Faces.

I'm confused. Is it set at the server/node/cluster level or at the application level?

Answer (score 0):

You're right - while the JSF implementation is configured via the application configuration options, the implementation selected there is used across the server.